# Making beforeFilter for module functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

A beforeFilter is that block of code which is executed before calling any function. I am new to javascript.

Lets say I have a module:

**SomeModule.js**

```
module.exports = {

    someFunction: function (arg) {
        //some logic here
    },
}
```

Now whenever I want to call the above function, I will do:

```
SomeModule.someFunction("helloWorld");
```

Like this you can assume I got many functions in the module but I want to execute some code before calling any function of the module, lets say I want to execute this line:

```
console.log("BeforeFilter Called");
```

So question is:
How can I ensure that the line gets executed before calling any function of the module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over properties of `SomeModule` and overwrite all properties which are functions:

```js
const SomeModule = {
  someFunction(a, b) {
    console.log('some function', a + b);
  }
};

for (const i in SomeModule) {
  if (typeof SomeModule[i] === 'function') {
    const originalFunction = SomeModule[i];
    SomeModule[i] = function (...args) {
      console.log('BeforeFilter Called');
      originalFunction(...args);
    };
  }
}

SomeModule.someFunction(3, 4);
```

Comment: Nice solution and example of overriding a function. I was really wondering how to override a function of javascript, you just solved that for me.

Comment: Is this possible for functions with different arguments without editing the structure of the function prototype?